How to add a helper table with unique( ) function
I received this really useful answer to my previous question:   UNIQUE/DISTINCT and Encoded query function, which works:
use a group by clause, applying max() to aggregate some column that you can later discard, like this:
select Q, Y, J, max(Q) where Y is not null and not Y like '[%' group by Q, Y, J

My question now is how to discard the 'max' group column at the end?  Attached is a screenshot of the first row I get with the end column a repeat of the first column.
The URL output is read-only so I cannot discard the column.

To drop the last column, you can use the CHOOSECOLS function:
=LET(arr,<your_formula>,CHOOSECOLS(arr,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(arr)-1)))

Replace <your_formula> with the formula that is generating the array.

Thanks. Sorry, I'm totally new to this. Where do I add the CHOOSECOLS function in the google sheet I'm using? I tired this in the google sheet and it didn't work: let (arr,select Q, Y, J, max(Q) where Y is not null and not Y like '[%' group by Q, Y, J, CHOOSECOLS(arr,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(arr)-1)))
